# What does #~ mean in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

For example:

```
#~ echo -e "Hello World"
```

I know # is for a comment and this line is a comment but on every line in the script that I am looking at it is placed after the #

Comment: It doesn't mean anything special. Maybe it's just the style of that programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These sort of comments are part of GNU `gettext` format for PO files (used for translations), in particular obsolete messages:

> [...] the messages which are not present in the source any more. All
>   obsolete messages are grouped at the end of the merged PO file, and
>   fully commented out by the #~ comment

Perhaps the author of your script generated those comments with the `gettext` toolset, or adopted the same syntax to communicate a similar meaning.

References:

https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/PO-Files.html
http://pology.nedohodnik.net/doc/user/en_US/ch-poformat.html